# AWK (illegal statement error with no more description)

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I'm getting "illegal character error" with no detailed description in AWK...

> awk: illegal statement at source line 1

Thanks AWK for help, but I have only one line code....
Please where is the errror?

```
awk '/^# /{$h}{print >"out" $h ".txt" }' File.txt
```

**SYSTEM:**

Mac OS 10.15

**THIS IS MY INPUT FILE**

```
# Heading 1

Rortox symbol....

qwtiRqto porsofql driRo....
DoifId thoso thifIds.....
fot qwwomplishif....

# Epilogue

You qro oxp......
qwwomplishi......

fot doifId so mqy....

# Chapter B

You qro oxpowtod to brifId you......
```

**MY DESIRED OUTPUT FILES**

**Heading 1.txt**

```
# Heading 1

Rortox symbol....

qwtiRqto porsofql driRo....
DoifId thoso thifIds.....
fot qwwomplishif....
```

**Epilogue.txt**

```
# Epilogue

You qro oxp......
qwwomplishi......

fot doifId so mqy....
```

**Chapter B**

```
# Chapter B
  
You qro oxpowtod to brifId you......
```

Comment: What do you expect `$h` to do?! I'll hazard the guess and say that's your error right there.  Hint: if error messages seem unclear, format the program over several lines and put it in a separate file. That will help you narrow down problems.

Comment: Like here https://justpaste.it/8r7z8 ... save that as xyz.awk, and invoke it with `awk -f xyz.awk File.txt`

Comment: ```$h``` is just variable to store the ```# Heading```.

Comment: `{h=substr($0,3); next}` would make more sense... Then get rid of the `'$'` in the next rule. E.g. `awk '/^#/{h=substr($0,3);next} {print > "out" h ".txt"}' file`

Comment: I tried your command in xzy.awk and now i'm getting: ```awk: bailing out at source line 1```. What he is complaing about? I have the ```'``` there I have ```\``` on start and end...

Comment: I tried your second script ```awk '/^#/{h=substr($0,3);next} {print > "out" h ".txt"}' file``` I'm getting same error like before: ```illegal statement at source line 1```.  Have you executed the command? Does it work for you with no error?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create an `awk` script that takes a filename as an argument and then carries out the rules producing the files separated as you describe above, you need to ensure you have the correct interpreter as the first line.

(**note** edited to remove `next` so the headings are included in the files)

For example, creating `xyz.awk` I would do:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^#/{ h=substr($0,3) }
    { print > "out" h ".txt" }
```

Check the correct path on Mac. Making the file executable with `chmod +x xyz.awk` and then running the script with your input in the input file produces:

```
'outChapter B.txt'
outEpilogue.txt
'outHeading 1.txt'
```

Containing:

```
$ cat outHeading\ 1.txt
# Heading 1

Rortox symbol....

qwtiRqto porsofql driRo....
DoifId thoso thifIds.....
fot qwwomplishif....
```

and

```
$ cat outEpilogue.txt
# Epilogue

You qro oxp......
qwwomplishi......

fot doifId so mqy....
```

and

```
$ cat outChapter\ B.txt
# Chapter B

You qro oxpowtod to brifId you......
```

**Running From The Command Line**

If instead of creating an `awk` script, you simply want to run the command directly from the command line:

```
awk '/^#/{ h=substr($0,3) } { print > "out" h ".txt" }' file
```

Will produce the exact same files.

I think you may be getting wrapped-around-the-axle with quoting. You do not need to wrap your rules in single-quotes inside an `awk` script -- but you do when running directly from the command line.

**String Concatenation Some Versions of awk**

With some versions of awk (I don't know which), you need to give the concatenation precedence over the redirection by wrapping the concatenation in parenthesis, e.g.

```
awk '/^#/{ h=substr($0,3) } { print > ("out" h ".txt") }' file
```

See [GNU Awk User's Guide - String Concatenation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Concatenation.html#Concatenation) Apparently all of the listed awks: BWK awk, gawk, and mawk, all get it right without having to include `(...)` but it also provides the note -- "you should not rely on this" -- meaning that some awks don't get it right.

**Running Against Linked File**

Running against the file [8263444c](https://pastebin.pl/view/download/8263444c) 85 files are created and no errors reported:

```
'outThis is not possible in the northern or southern hemisphere.txt'
'outVertex Conjunct Ascendant.txt'
'outVertex Conjunct Jupiter.txt'
'outVertex Conjunct Mars.txt'
'outVertex Conjunct Mercury.txt'
'outVertex Conjunct Midheaven.txt'
'outVertex Conjunct Moon.txt'
'outVertex Conjunct Neptune.txt'
'outVertex Conjunct Pluto.txt'
'outVertex Conjunct Saturn.txt'
'outVertex Conjunct Sun.txt'
'outVertex Conjunct Uranus.txt'
'outVertex Conjunct Venus.txt'
'outVertex Opposition Ascendant.txt'
'outVertex Opposition Jupiter.txt'
'outVertex Opposition Mars.txt'
'outVertex Opposition Mercury.txt'
'outVertex Opposition Midheaven.txt'
'outVertex Opposition Moon.txt'
'outVertex Opposition Neptune.txt'
'outVertex Opposition Pluto.txt'
'outVertex Opposition Saturn.txt'
'outVertex Opposition Sun.txt'
'outVertex Opposition Uranus.txt'
'outVertex Opposition Venus.txt'
'outVertex Quincunx Ascendant.txt'
'outVertex Quincunx Jupiter.txt'
'outVertex Quincunx Mars.txt'
'outVertex Quincunx Mercury.txt'
'outVertex Quincunx Midheaven.txt'
'outVertex Quincunx Moon.txt'
'outVertex Quincunx Neptune.txt'
'outVertex Quincunx Pluto.txt'
'outVertex Quincunx Saturn.txt'
'outVertex Quincunx Sun.txt'
'outVertex Quincunx Uranus.txt'
'outVertex Quincunx Venus.txt'
'outVertex Sextile Ascendant.txt'
'outVertex Sextile Jupiter.txt'
'outVertex Sextile Mars.txt'
'outVertex Sextile Mercury.txt'
'outVertex Sextile Midheaven.txt'
'outVertex Sextile Moon.txt'
'outVertex Sextile Neptune.txt'
'outVertex Sextile Pluto.txt'
'outVertex Sextile Saturn.txt'
'outVertex Sextile Sun.txt'
'outVertex Sextile Uranus.txt'
'outVertex Sextile Venus.txt'
'outVertex Square Ascendant.txt'
'outVertex Square Jupiter.txt'
'outVertex Square Mars.txt'
'outVertex Square Mercury.txt'
'outVertex Square Midheaven.txt'
'outVertex Square Moon.txt'
'outVertex Square Neptune.txt'
'outVertex Square Pluto.txt'
'outVertex Square Saturn.txt'
'outVertex Square Sun.txt'
'outVertex Square Uranus.txt'
'outVertex Square Venus.txt'
'outVertex Trine Ascendant.txt'
'outVertex Trine Jupiter.txt'
'outVertex Trine Mars.txt'
'outVertex Trine Mercury.txt'
'outVertex Trine Midheaven.txt'
'outVertex Trine Moon.txt'
'outVertex Trine Neptune.txt'
'outVertex Trine Pluto.txt'
'outVertex Trine Saturn.txt'
'outVertex Trine Sun.txt'
'outVertex Trine Uranus.txt'
'outVertex Trine Venus.txt'
'outVertex in Aquarius.txt'
'outVertex in Aries.txt'
'outVertex in Cancer.txt'
'outVertex in Capricorn.txt'
'outVertex in Gemini.txt'
'outVertex in Leo.txt'
'outVertex in Libra.txt'
'outVertex in Pisces.txt'
'outVertex in Sagittarius.txt'
'outVertex in Scorpio.txt'
'outVertex in Taurus.txt'
'outVertex in Virgo.txt'
```

Give that a try and let me know if you have problems. Note, I have no Mac to test on.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem! The lessons learned from all of this, is that **on Mac OS never use AWK but GAWK.**

0. [Dataset (here)](https://pastebin.pl/view/8263444c): as `File.txt`
1. `brew install gawk`
2. AWK script: `Command.awk` inside:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^#/{ h=substr($0,3); }
    { print > ( h ".txt") }
```

3. `gawk -f Command.awk File.txt`
4. Done!

So the lessons learn is that on Mac OS never use **AWK** but **GAWK**.

Thank you @David C. for your great help and time. Without you I will be not able to go thru this. Thank you @James for testing on Mac OS.

Comment: Right, also, use `pcregrep`, not `grep`.